# UrlRequest not working for my second call

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy and trying to learn it, but i am stuck with this problem.
As you can see i am able to call url in `AddLocationForm` class but cannot call in `CurrentWeather` class. To be precise, function `weather_retrive` is not called.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,StringProperty,NumericProperty,ListProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton 
import  json
# from kivy.factory import Factory

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):
    current_weather= ObjectProperty()

    def show_current_weather(self,location=None):
        self.clear_widgets()
        print "hello {}".format(location)
        print "killer {}".format(self.current_weather)

        if self.current_weather is None:
            self.current_weather= CurrentWeather()
        if location is not None:
            self.current_weather = CurrentWeather(location=location)
        self.current_weather.update_weather()
        self.add_widget(self.current_weather)

    def show_add_location_form(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(AddLocationForm())




class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()

    def search_location(self,**kwargs):
        search_template = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/search.json?key=310544670f5e490aadb121033173006&q={}"
        search_textwithnospace = self.search_input.text.replace(" ","_") # coverting GUI text input "space " to " underscore " format for API to understand 
        search_url = search_template.format(search_textwithnospace)
        print search_url
        self.request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)
        # print "first before",self.request.result
        # print "The user searched for {}". format(self.search_input.text)

    def found_location(self,request,data):
        # print "after",self.request.result
        cities = ["{}".format(d['name'])for d in data]
        it = iter(cities)
        tucity = zip(it)
        print "\n ".join(cities)

        self.search_results.item_strings = tucity
        del self.search_results.adapter.data[:]
        self.search_results.adapter.data.extend(tucity)
        self.search_results._trigger_reset_populate()

    def args_converter(self,index,data_item):
        city= data_item
        return {'location':(city)}

class CurrentWeather(BoxLayout):
    location=ListProperty(['Mumbai, India'])
    temp=NumericProperty()


    def update_weather(self,**kwargs):

        weather_template = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=310544670f5e490aadb121033173006&q={}"
        string = ''.join(self.location)
        weather_url=weather_template.format(string)
        print "infact {}".format(string)
        print weather_url
        request2= UrlRequest(weather_url,self.weather_retrive)
        # print "before",request2.result 


    def weather_retrive(self, request2, data2,*args):
        print data2
        print "after",self.request2.result 
        self.temp= data2['current']['temp_c']
        print self.temp


class LocationButton(ListItemButton):
    location = ListProperty()




class citysearchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WeatherRoot()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    citysearchApp().run()
```

Comment: this looks like the book from dusty philipps from oreilly. they are providing code for each chapter. Have you looked at that or are you trying to implement something which they did not cover in the book?

Comment: 90% is from the book but the API given in the book is not working so i am using new API and i was able to get the result . when i call the api in the first class it works but the problem arise when i try the second class .

Comment: i used the book a couple of months ago. Back then it was still working. You only had to generate an api key through their site first.